# How to run python scripts on your server?

Tags: python, apache, unix

I have mod_python installed on my server, but if I want to acceses a python script - let's say httü://site.com/**something.py** the script doesn't run, the download box "pops up"

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider a lightweight framework such as http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/ as it isn't very practical in the modern day to have CGI-style python scripts.

And I would use `mod_wsgi` instead of `mod_python` as the latter is a bit outdated.

Answer (score 0):

This should be on ServerFault. By the way, `mod_python` is deprecated, use WSGI instead.

Answer (score 0):

Is mod_py configured ok?
http://www.modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/inst-apacheconfig.html